# Excel nested if problems?

Tags: excel

i have an excel table with +19k lines.
Let's assume table has 2 columns ( Departmant,id).
there are 25 departments that each has unique id.

What formula can i use to get each of them's id correctly.

i tried using if, but i guess it doesnt work with + 25 if's in it..

is there any easy way to do it ?

i'm a beginnner and i'm working on this table for 3 days!.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from MrExcel.com. Untested

```
Sub FindDistinctValues()
Dim LastRowFrom As Long
Dim LastRowTo As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim temp As Integer
Dim found As Boolean

'determines the last row that contains data in column A
LastRowFrom = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Loop for each entry in column A
For i = 2 To LastRowFrom
   'get the next value from column A
   temp = Range("A" & i).Value

   'Determine the last row with data in column B
   LastRowTo = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'initialize j and found
   j = 1
   found = False

   'Loop through "To List" until a match is found or the list has been searched
   Do
      'check if the value exists in B column
      If temp = Range("B" & j).Value Then
         found = True
      End If
      'increment j
      j = j + 1
      Loop Until found Or j = LastRowTo + 1

   'if the value is not already in column B
   If Not found Then
      Range("B" & j).Value = temp
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```